# Saving from a view model to a model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two models, a code model and a tag model which are linked by a many to many relationship. I am trying to add a code entry that includes a possible selection of many tags using a view model (using check boxes for the tags in my view). I am getting the error:

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[StoRed.Models.Code]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[StoRed.Models.CodeTagViewModel]'.**

It feels like I need to somehow convert my data to the acceptable format before trying to save it into the table but I'm new to MVC and I am having trouble finding any useful information on the internet about my specific problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code model

```
public class Code
{
    [Key]
    public int CodeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Project { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string CMS { get; set; }

    public int DotNetVersion { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Dependencies { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public string CodeFile { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string TFSLocation { get; set; }

    ////Creates a relationship in the DB with Tag
    //[ForeignKey("TagID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    ////Purely for API
    //[Required]
    public int TagID { get; set; }
}
```

The Tag model

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int TagID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Code> Code { get; set; }
}
```

The context

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Code> Code { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

The view model

```
public class CodeTagViewModel
{
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public Tag TagID { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }


    public int CodeID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public string CMS { get; set; }
    public int DotNetVersion { get; set; }
    public string Dependencies { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string CodeFile { get; set; }
    public string TFSLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Relevant part of the code controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CodeTagViewModel codeTagViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Code code = new Code();
            Tag tag = new Tag();

            var codeTag = new CodeTagViewModel();

            code.Title = codeTagViewModel.Title;
            code.Description = codeTagViewModel.Description;
            code.DateAdded = codeTagViewModel.DateAdded;
            code.LastUpdated = codeTagViewModel.LastUpdated;
            code.Project = codeTagViewModel.Project;
            code.CMS = codeTagViewModel.CMS;
            code.DotNetVersion = codeTagViewModel.DotNetVersion;
            code.Dependencies = codeTagViewModel.Dependencies;
            code.Author = codeTagViewModel.Author;
            code.CodeFile = codeTagViewModel.CodeFile;
            code.TFSLocation = codeTagViewModel.TFSLocation;
            code.Tags = codeTagViewModel.Tags;

            db.Code.Add(code);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(codeTagViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: I see that you have a many to many relationship between Code and Tag did you specify how this relationship is mapped in your context ?

Comment: I've added the context, I don't think I have but checking my database in SQL I can see it is a many to many

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to create some kind of provider/manager/service/factory/handler - choose a name that makes most sense in terms of the job it is doing within the flow of data through your system - that is responsible for taking the ViewModel and mapping the properties of the ViewModel into an instance of the domain model before persisting the domain model to the data store, either itself or by passing the hydrated domain model to a repository layer. You can either do this manually or by using something like AutoMapper. Here's a quick manual example:

Create a `CommandHandlers` folder in your web project with the interface and dependant handler:

```
public interface ICodeCommandHandler
{
    int Save(CodeTagViewModel input);
}

public class CodeCommandHandler : ICodeCommandHandler
{
    private IRepository<Code> repository;

    public CodeCommandHandler(IRepository<Code> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public int Save(CodeTagViewModel input)
    {
        Code code = new Code();
        Tag tag = new Tag();
        code.Title = input.Title;
        code.Description = input.Description;
        code.DateAdded = input.DateAdded;
        code.LastUpdated = input.LastUpdated;
        code.Project = input.Project;
        code.CMS = input.CMS;
        code.DotNetVersion = input.DotNetVersion;
        code.Dependencies = input.Dependencies;
        code.Author = input.Author;
        code.CodeFile = input.CodeFile;
        code.TFSLocation = input.TFSLocation;
        code.Tags.Add(tag);

        return repository.Save(code);

    }
}
```

Then in your controller, inject the ICodeCommandHandler in via constructor injection, the same as you do with the repository in the `CodeCommandHandler`:

```
private readonly ICodeCommandHandler commandHandler;

public CodeController(ICodeCommandHandler commandHandler)
{
    this.commandHandler = commandHandler;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CodeTagViewModel codeTagViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(codeTagViewModel);
    }

    var id = codeCommandHandler.Save(codeTagViewModel);
    // maybe do something useful with the document id after save
    return RedirectToAction("Index");  
}
```

To keep the `Repository` nice and simple, here's how that could look:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    int Save(T entity);
}

public class CodeRepository : IRepository<Code>
{
    public int Save(Code entity)
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            context.Code.Add(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I've not gone into detail about the dependency injection side of things as that wasn't part of the question but this should give you an idea of where to start

Comment: I'm still having trouble getting this to work. I've installed Auto-Mapper but I'm having trouble implementing it. Not understanding everything from the ground up is really hindering my ability to get my head around how to solve this problem and what exactly is happening. If you could provide any additional help (especially with how to go about using automapper) that would be great thank you.

Comment: I would suggest performing the mapping manually to start with, just until you get everything working end-to-end. You can always swap `AutoMapper` in after everything else is working. Here's some links for `AutoMapper`: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started and https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki

Comment: I'm trying to do it manually but the way you have worded the answer is not very beginner friendly and I'm having trouble understanding what is going on. I appreciate that you took the time out to write a very detailed answer for me and for that I thank you. Where does the first code snippet go?

Comment: Fair enough :) - will update the answer to break it down a bit more - are you OK with the Dependency Injection side of things or shall I expand on that?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the repositories, haven't seen them before and intellisense isn't liking the IRepository<Code>'s and is saying that not all code paths in Save return a value

Comment: Oops - well spotted - fixed :) - the `Repository` is just a wrapper around the `DbContext` - it's just a way of abstracting the implementation details of the `DbContext` away from the handler. Instead of making the handler dependant on `DbContext`, it is dependant on a generic `IRepository` - within the `IRepository` `Save` method, you would call `db.Code.Add(code);` and `return db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: It's still giving me problems with IRepository<Code>: Type or namespace could not be found

Comment: And when writing the code to my controller should: 

public CodeController(ICodeCommandHandler commandHandler)
{
    this.commandHandler = commandHandler;
}

be: this.codecommandHandler ? I'm getting a no definition error.

Sorry for all the questions I'm trying to figure out what is going on. And thank you for the help :)

Comment: Have you created it? That was one I didn't include in the original answer - if I get some time later I'll fill out the `Repository` part but you basically need to create a `Repository` that uses your `Context` and has a `Save(Code code)` method that uses the `Context` to save the object.

Comment: Ah okay yeah, I have no idea how to do that. I'll look at some guides and make an attempt :) But if you do get some time that would be amazing thanks

Comment: Yeah it hasn't been going well haha

Comment: This should help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94782/Revisiting-the-Repository-and-Unit-of-Work-Pattern

Comment: I read that, and followed through to his naive example and still can't get it to work. I also have two O'Reilly books (one on EF4 and the other on MVC4) I just don't understand why I can't get my head around it. It feels like what I want to do shouldn't be this complicated :(

Comment: Maybe worth posting a new SO question outlining the problem that you're having? It doesn't sound like it's completely related to this original question any more so might be better as a new one? I can't really help without seeing the code that you're struggling with

Comment: The problem is still dealing with the saving the tags through the code controller. But I haven't been able to implement your answer because it is quite hard for me to understand being new to this, and different sites are showing me different ways of going about solving this problem so it would feel a bit redundant asking the question again. I just can't seem to actually implement any of the solutions because of my lack of programming experience.